Group By Need to Avoid the Duplicate in the SQL Query
The result of a table is as follows:



Name
Postion
subordinate
Country
Rate




John
Manager
Jose
IN
50


John
Manager
Raju
SR
25


John
Manager
CRISS
IN
30


JOHN
Manager
DON
BN
10


John
Manager
Jose
IN
300


John
Manager
Raju
SR
85


John
Manager
CRISS
IN
450


JOHN
Manager
DON
BN
100


MATHEW
HRM
ALI
BH
20


MATHEW
HRM
Neethu
IN
20


MATHEW
HRM
SEENA
IN
20



And the actual result I need to get is as follows:



Name
Postion
subordinate
Country
Rate




John
Manager
Jose,Raju,Criss,DON
IN,SR,BN
1050


MATHEW
HRM
ALI,Neethu,SEENA
BH,IN
60



The query I tried is:
SELECT
    A.Name AS Name, A.Position AS Position, 
    STRING_AGG(B.Subordinate, ',') AS Sabordinates,
    STRING_AGG(A.Country, ',') AS Country, 
    SUM(C.Rate) 
FROM
    Emp A 
LEFT JOIN
    Sabordinate B ON A.ID = B.SabId  
LEFT JOIN
    Cost C ON C.SId = B.SabId
GROUP BY 
    A.Name, A.Position

I am getting the result as follows:



Name
Postion
subordinate
Country
Rate




John
Manager
Jose,Raju,Criss,DON,Jose,Raju,Criss,DON
IN,SR,IN,BN,IN,SR,IN,BN
1050


MATHEW
HRM
ALI,Neethu,SEENA
BH,IN,IN
60



It is repeating the subordinate name and one country twice or triple (times of name repeating is repeating as much).
I need only one name and country only one time if it is repeating

Don't think DISTINCT is available in STRING_AGG(yet). You can probably pre-aggregate the values and then do STRING_AGG on them, although it won't help the countries. But you shouldn't distinct them anyway, because then you don't know which country belong to which person

ok , let me try

The STRING_AGG() function doesn't support the DISTINCT modifier, so a possible option is the old FOR XML PATH string aggregation approach:
SELECT 
   e.Name, 
   e.Position,
   Subordinate = (
      SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(Subordinate, ',')
      FROM Emp
      WHERE Name = e.Name AND Position = e.Position
      FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE     
   ).value('.', 'varchar(max)'),
   Country = (
      SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(Country, ',')
      FROM Emp
      WHERE Name = e.Name AND Position = e.Position
      FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE     
   ).value('.', 'varchar(max)'),
   Rate = SUM(e.Rate)
FROM Emp e
GROUP BY e.Name, e.Position


Seems like pre-aggregation would work here. So you aggregate for your subordinates first, then your countries and then finally over all.
SELECT Name,
       Postion, --Position?
       subordinate,
       Country,
       CONVERT(int,Rate) AS Rate
INTO dbo.YourTable
FROM (VALUES('John','Manager','Jose','IN','50'),
            ('John','Manager','Raju','SR','25'),
            ('John','Manager','CRISS','IN','30'),
            ('JOHN','Manager','DON','BN','10'),
            ('John','Manager','Jose','IN','300'),
            ('John','Manager','Raju','SR','85'),
            ('John','Manager','CRISS','IN','450'),
            ('JOHN','Manager','DON','BN','100'),
            ('MATHEW','HRM','ALI','BH','20'),
            ('MATHEW','HRM','Neethu','IN','20'),
            ('MATHEW','HRM','SEENA','IN','20'))V(Name,Postion,subordinate,Country,Rate);
GO
WITH Subordinates AS(
        SELECT Name,
           Postion, --Position?
           subordinate,
           Country,
           SUM(Rate) AS Rate
    FROM dbo.YourTable
    GROUP BY Name,
             Postion, --Position?
             subordinate,
             Country),
Countries AS(
    SELECT Name,
           Postion, --Position?
           STRING_AGG(subordinate,',') AS subordinates,
           Country,
           SUM(Rate) AS Rate
    FROM Subordinates
    GROUP BY Name,
             Postion, --Position?
             Country)
SELECT Name,
       Postion, --Position?
       STRING_AGG(subordinates,',') AS subordinates,
       STRING_AGG(Country,',') AS Countries,
       SUM(Rate) AS Rate
FROM Countries
GROUP BY Name,
         Postion; --Position?
GO
DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable;

If your data is more normalised , and you have different tables for the different parts, you could likely pre-aggregate in subqueries instead, which may be easier, but we don't have sample data for that.

You can use distinct to fetch unique value
SELECT 
    A.Name as Name, 
    A.Position as Position, 
    STRING_AGG(DISTINCT Subordinates.Subordinate, ',') as Subordinates, 
    STRING_AGG(DISTINCT A.Country, ',') as Country, 
    SUM(C.Rate) 
FROM 
    Emp A 
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT SabId, Subordinate FROM Sabordinate) AS Subordinates ON A.ID = Subordinates.SabId
LEFT JOIN 
    Cost C ON C.SId = Subordinates.SabId 
GROUP BY 
    A.Name, A.Position;


I think you are missing the join keyword between the table and the subquery

DISTINCT Country ?

No!! unique Subordinate will does our work
